# 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict' in Python 3. Unsure of why this is happening as list values are integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, typeerror

I am working on a project and getting a type error that I do not understand how to correct. I am looking for help on what I am overlooking and how to correct this error.

Below is the function that is creating the error. I have printed the dictionary and the lists I have created so that you all can see what the data is. It seems to me like all of the indices in the list ARE integers and that is what is confusing me.

```
def summarize_points(submissions):
    print(submissions[0])
    pointsPossible = []
    groupWeight = []
    userScore = []   
    for assignment in submissions:
        if assignment['workflow_state'] == 'graded':
            pointsPossible.append(int(assignment['assignment'] 
            ['points_possible']))
            groupWeight.append(int(assignment['assignment']['group'] 
            ['group_weight']))
            userScore.append(int(assignment['score']))
        pass
    pass
    print('\n\n\n\nTest Data \n\n\n')
    print('pointsPossible')
    print(pointsPossible)
    print('\ngroupWeight')
    print(groupWeight)
    print('\nuserScore')
    print(userScore)
    weightedTotalPoints = []
    weightedUserScore = []
    for assignment in submissions:
        weightedtotalPointsAddition = int(pointsPossible[assignment]) * int(groupWeight[assignment])
    weightedTotalPoints.append(weightedtotalPointsAddition)
    weightedUserScoreAddition = int(userScore[assignment]) * int(groupWeight[assignment])
    weightedUserScore.append(weightedUserScoreAddition)
currentGrade = sum(weightedUserScore) / sum(weightedTotalPoints)
currentGrade = round(currentGrade)
print(weightedtotalPoints)
print(weightedUserScore)
print(currentGrade)
```

Below this is what is output to the console

```
{'missing': False, 'submitted_at': '2017-08-28T23:51:13Z', 'assignment': {'due_at': '2017-08-30T16:20:00Z', 'lock_at': '2017-10-01T00:00:00Z', 'name': '#1.2) Quiz: Introduction', 'id': 270567, 'unlock_at': '2017-08-27T16:40:00Z', 'points_possible': 10.0, 'assignment_group_id': 82390, 'group': {'rules': {}, 'name': 'Learning Quizzes', 'id': 82390, 'group_weight': 25}}, 'assignment_id': 270567, 'late': False, 'attempt': 3, 'grader_id': 10926, 'workflow_state': 'graded', 'score': 9, 'graded_at': '2017-09-12T13:04:04Z', 'seconds_late': -145726, 'excused': False, 'user_id': 42}




Test Data 



pointsPossible
[10, 10, 1, 6, 10, 1, 7, 10, 4, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 10, 2, 7, 6, 10, 7, 5, 10, 4, 6, 5, 0, 5, 16, 7, 3, 6, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 7, 5, 9, 4, 5, 6, 2, 21, 6, 5, 10, 3, 4, 9, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 17, 8, 5, 11, 4, 14, 3, 5, 7, 3, 4, 9, 4, 8, 3, 5, 3, 7, 10, 5, 10, 7, 7, 7, 10, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5]

groupWeight
[25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 10, 25, 10, 25, 25, 10, 10, 10, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 25, 10, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 10]

userScore
[9, 9, 0, 5, 9, 0, 6, 9, 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 9, 1, 7, 5, 9, 6, 4, 9, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 14, 6, 2, 5, 4, 9, 9, 9, 4, 6, 4, 8, 3, 4, 5, 1, 19, 5, 4, 9, 2, 3, 8, 3, 5, 1, 4, 5, 15, 7, 4, 10, 3, 13, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 8, 3, 7, 2, 4, 2, 6, 9, 4, 9, 6, 6, 6, 9, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4]
```

Below is the error

```
File "path", line 97, in summarize_points
weightedtotalPointsAddition = int(pointsPossible[assignment]) * 
int(groupWeight[assignment])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Comment: According to the output of your first `print`, `submissions` is a list of dicts, not integers, so `assignment` is a `dict` as well.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes but I am trying to pull out values from the dictionary and put them in a list. The 3 other prints are lists of integers

Comment: `assignment` is a dict. You know that because you're accessing `assignment['workflow_state']` and things like that. Then later in the same function you start trying to use it as an index with `pointsPossible[assignment]` and `groupWeight[assignment]`

Comment: @khelwood that was poor naming of the variable. I changed assignment in the for loop to entry. With that, I am trying to take the values out of the dict and into a list. Once I get the list, I am trying to use pointsPossible[entry] to access the specific index of the list and do the math with that respective value.

Comment: Oh I understand what you are all telling me now! I cannot be running the for loop over the dictionary! I had no idea that caused problems.I thought the for loops just processed it as numbers. 

For example, if the dict had 100 values and it had run 3 times and we had for loop like below:
    for entry in submissions
then entry would have a value of 2 and submissions would have a value of 99

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clear: your `assignment` variable is a `dict`, as your `print(submissions[0])` shows, and since `pointsPossible` is a list, you should enter an `integer` or a `slice` to call elements from it. So even if your `list` is comprised of `integers`, when you call `list[index]`, is the `index` that should contain an `integer` or `slice`.

Checking your code, I'd guess that you're trying to use the value from `points_possible` that's in your dict `assignment`. 
One confusing thing, is that you called the elements from `submission` as `assignment`, which is the same name from one of your JSON keys, so this is the confusion.

In order to call the right element from your json, you should call `dictName["assignment"]["points_possible"]`.

When you call the `for` loop, you're calling each element from `submissions` as `assignment` as well.

So the right call would be:
`assignment["assignment"]["points_possible"]`

To achieve what you want, just change `int(pointsPossible[assignment])` for `pointPossible[int(assignment["assignment"]["points_possible"])]` that should do the trick.

If you wanted to access another element from your `dict`, but inside the `assignment` key on your dict, just change `points_possible` for the right one.

PS: In case you encounter other problem, just let me know and I update the code here.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I figured this out and it was a few things. Firstly, the naming of assignment for the for loop was a dumb and confusing decision. Secondly, I changed the second for loop to a while loop that iterates over the length of the list. This seems to have fixed all of my problems. Thank you for the help